# Using IAM to store certificates in order to use them in a NodeJs server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-iam

I have a web server implemented in node + express and now I'm supposed to make it secure by implementing a two-way SSL.

I managed to do so by signing a bunch of self-signed certificates. Following an example I've found online, my code looks something like this:

```
const app = express();
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
const options = {
    ca: 'ca-crt.pem',
    key: 'server-key.pem',
    cert: 'server-crt.pem',
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: true
};
const server = https.createServer(options, app);
```

Of course, it is a bad idea to keep the certificate files on your EC2 instance. So I stored them in a bucket on S3 and loaded them in the code above. But then I came across [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html) which says that I can use IAM services to store and retrieve certificates on AWS.

Definitely, I prefer to use IAM as it is designed for security purposes. But the problem I have with it is that [the documentation says](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs.html#get-server-certificate):

> You cannot download or retrieve a private key from IAM after you
>   upload it.

So my question is, how am I supposed to set up my server if IAM will not give me back my private key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability to store SSL certs in IAM is something what was done before the introduction of the AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) and was intended to be used with AWS services that supported it (i.e. ELBs)

I would strongly recommend putting your node servers behind a load balancer, and using the AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) to provision an actual cert.  If you need to have traffic between the ELB and your server encrypted, you can continue to use self-signed certs - the ELB will not validate them.

Comment: Could you please clarify something for me? In your scenario, can I use a self-signed with ACM? Also, if I use ACM and ELB (self-signed certs or not) will my server's code know about the certificates? Or the server's code will receive the requests already decrypted?

Comment: I don't think you can use a self-signed cert with ACM, but since AWS provides them for free that really shouldn't matter.  The back-end code won't know anything about the cert - that's sort of the point - but it will know if the client connected securely or not.  The ELB will set header values that the node server can use to determine how and where the client connected from.